# Python Beginner, function is supposed to sort according to string EX 'asc'. Function does not sort double digits correctly EX 23 is between 2 and 3

Tags: python, sorting

I am attaching the code below, I know there are some ways to clean it up or make it more efficient and would appreciate those tips as well, but I am mainly just struggling figuring out why double digit numbers in the list are not being sorted accordingly. 23 is between 2 and 3 for example, single digits work fine. Thank you for your time.

```
## Creating a function that takes in two strings and returns a list in a specific orientation depending on what string is entered

## Couldn't figure out how to make double digits go in order

def sort_list(list, string):
    if string == 'desc':
        list = sorted(list.split(), reverse = True)
        return list                     ## First section returns list in opposite order if 'desc'
    elif string == 'asc':
        list = sorted(list.split())
        return list                     ## Second retuns list in ascending order if 'asc' 
    elif string == 'none':
        list = list.split()
        return list                    ## Third returns list in same order if 'none' is chosen

    
def main():

    list = input('Please input numbers with spaces in between to create a list:\n')

    string = input('Please enter what order you would like your list returned to you:\n')


    print(sort_list(list,string))


main()
```

Comment: Strings have dictionary sorting, so just like `"a" < "ab" < "b"`, you are seeing `"2" < "23" < "3"`. If you want to have proper numbers sorting, convert them to float/int or write a custom key function.

Comment: Also, don't call your variables with built-in names like `list` or `string`.

Answer (score 0):

A few pointers

- Don't use names like list, string which are reserved words in python.
- Avoid code duplication. You are calling `split` on the same list multiple times which can be avoided
- Sorted will sort even strings and in your code you are sorting strings. Instead you want to sort integers. So you have to convert the strings into integers by using `int()`.

```
def sort_list(numbers_list, sort_order):
    numbers_list = [int(item) for item in numbers_list.split(" ") if item]
    if sort_order == 'desc':
        numbers_list = sorted(numbers_list, reverse=True)
    elif sort_order == 'asc':
        numbers_list = sorted(numbers_list)
    return numbers_list


def main():
    numbers_list = input(
        'Please input numbers with spaces in between to create a list:\n')
    sort_order = input(
        'Please enter what order you would like your list returned to you:\n')
    print(sort_list(numbers_list, sort_order))
```

Here in the below line I am doing a list comprehension.
`numbers_list = [int(item) for item in numbers_list.split(" ") if item]`

This can be replaced with a basic for loop if you want as well.

```
new_num_list = []
for item in numbers_list.split(" "):
    if item:
        new_num_list.append(int(item))
```